# Does anyone know what this piece is? (piano)

Tags: piano

(includes a timestamp to the section with the piece)

Comment: Sounds very early-18th century, like Haydn, Mozart, Clementi, etc.  I don't recognize it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is from the Musica Para Ninos - Cumpleanos Infantiles collection.

They have hundreds of songs.  Good luck finding which one.
Ich sprechen sie Deutch, un poco.

Comment: They took it from the YouTube Audio Library, it's called "Claudio the Worm"